# Pretty url in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, publishing-site, publishing-page, url, publishing

The url's on our intranet are pretty, i.e. http://intranet/test, but we want to show full path of the page, like this http://intranet/test/default.aspx

I don't know why we get pretty url and have been trying to find out how to get back the old fashioned url's.

Any ideas how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things that control this in site settings --> navigation.

Managed Navigation -- use a term set for navigation

Add new pages to navigation automatically -- a new item is added to the termset for each new page

Create friendly URLs for new pages automatically -- This is what you're concerned about - the page shows up in the URL without the .aspx.

So, a couple options:

1. disable the create friendly URLs for new pages - this will work, but only applies to new pages.
2. Do the above, but also open the term store management tool, navigate to the term set for the current site collection (at the bottom on the left), drill down to the particular page (term) you want to change, and on the navigation tab switch it from a term-driven page to a simple link (repeat this step for every existing page)
3. Change the navigation for both the top and current to structural instead of managed. (this is a separate option and can be done instead of the first two)

edit: to change this setting from powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$web = get-spweb "http://someSharePointUrl"
$navSettings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings($web)

$navSettings.AddNewPagesToNavigation = $false
$navSettings.CreateFriendlyUrlsForNewPages = $false
$navSettings.Update()
```

Comment: Hi. Where can I find the setting for disabling friendly urls for new pages ?

Comment: site settings --> navigation --> Create friendly URLs for new pages automatically (it's a checkbox about halfway down the page)

Comment: If you got any powershell script for fixing that, please share :)

Comment: For which option? deselecting the add new pages automatically? (how many sites do you have to do this to?)

Comment: For these options: Create friendly URLs for new pages automatically and Add new pages to navigation automatically. I need to do it on a lot of sites, but if I get a sample on how to do it on one, I can fix looping and doing it on the other sites :)

Comment: See the edit...